# How to put a PhP variable inside an img src?

Tags: php

I'm trying to put an image in my website, but I need the **src** to be a **php variable**, and I get the console error that "Path couldn't be found", but the Image should be there.

Setting image variable

```
<?php
    $rand = rand(1,2);
    $image = "imagePath";

    switch ($rand) {
        case 1:
            $image = "images/image1.jpg";
            break;
        case 2:
            $image = "images/image2.png";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
?>
```

Trying to retrieve it

```
<img src="<?php $image ?>" />
```

Error message

> *file:///C:/Users/Leonardo/Desktop/Games/M/Site/%3C?php%20$image%20?%3E*
>   Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

How to insert the `$image` path inside a **src** attribute in an **img**?

Comment: I don't get why this got negatively repped...

Comment: Please put the error message text in your answer.

Comment: Also, you should `echo` the variable in your image tag `<img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" />` and make sure your PHP code is actually being executed by your webserver

Comment: this code worked https://ideone.com/wQUYPz problem is from address or ...

Comment: Use `<img src="<?=$image;?>" />`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to echo your variable:

```php
<img src="<?php echo $image; ?>">
```

Also make sure your PHP is being executed on the server side, not as a static file. Is this in a file with a `.php` extension?

Comment: No... <?php is literally in the output URL

Comment: @EricJ. this means you need to save the file as a `.php` file and run the file on a server that supports PHP. The file will not run on your local machine without XAMPP or WAMP support / Setup and the downloading of Zend (I believe).

Answer (score 1):

You have the code

```
<img src="<?php $image ?>" />
```

However the error message (which please include in plain text, not as an image) indicates that the

file:///C:/Users/Leonardo/Desktop/Games/M/Site/**%3C?php**

Additionally, you need to echo the contents of $image.

It's unclear from the context of your question where this tag is located, but it is apparently not in a PHP page or the PHP page is not being processed as such by the web server.

Answer (score 0):

you need to echo out the variable so:

```
<img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" />
```

You should also make sure you are serializing your output.

Comment: No... <?php is literally in the output URL.

Comment: Didn't work either. Got file:///C:/Users/Leonardo/Desktop/Games/M/Site/%3C?php%20echo%20$image;%20?%3E Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: @Colmantio is your file extension .php? and are you running it on a server?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Error Message, it appears that the PHP code is not being processed, just written to HTML as-is.

Another suggestion: make an array of image paths, and create a random index based on it's size. That will be easier to maintain when you change images around.

```
$images = array(
    'images/correr.jpg',
    'images/banhammer.png'
);

$image_index = rand(0, sizeof($images)-1);
$image = $images[$image_index];
```

Comment: since you placed the paths inside a container (array), you could use `array_rand` too